# Sets as the Union of Elements: $\{b,c\} = \{b\} \cup \{c\}$

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I had the following very simple question:

> If all elementary outcomes are equally likely $S = \{a,b,c,d\}$, $A = \{a,b,c\}$ and $B=\{c,d\}$ find $P(A|B)$

The answer is $\frac{1/4}{1/4+1/4} = 1/2$

But what bothered me was afterwards I started thinking about $B=\{c,d\}$ as only being true if the elements $b$ **and** $c$ occurred in it. Which makes intuitive sense (kind of) because, for example {b} ≠ B

- This would mean that assuming each element was independent. $P(B) = (1/4)(1/4)$ which gives a bogus answer to the original question.
- Also obviously if $B = \{b\}$ and $\{c\}$ then $B = \{b\} \cap \{c\}$ which is just the empty set.  Also bogus for the question.

So clearly $B = \{b\} \cup \{c\} = \{b,c\}$

**Question**

But I'm struggling to reconcile the idea that $B = \{b\} \cup \{c\}$ implies we could have $b$ or $c$, i.e. we don't have to have $b$ and $c$. But the set B only is B if it contains $b$ and $c$.

Could someone very kindly help me out of this mess!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event $B$ happens if one of elementary outcomes in it happens (and by definition, one and only one elementary outcome happens).

For example, consider 4-sided dice, $c$ is "we got 3", $d$ is "we got 4". Then $B$ happens iff we got $3$ or we got $4$.

$\{b\} \neq B$, but if $B' = \{b\}$ happens, then $B$ also happens.

Note that events (sets of elementary outcomes) are not true or false, they happen or not happen.

Comment: Thank you! - This is so obvious, yet I'm still stuck, it's kind of mind blowing lol. So I get what you're saying in that if $B'$ is a subset of $B$ then if $B'$ happens $B$ must have happened also. But somehow I can't quite settle that in my head, with the understanding of set theory outside of probability, where the set contains each of these elements, and if it doesn't then it's a different set e.g. a subset. You've helped a-lot, but I'm not quite there yet, any other pointers? Thanks!

Comment: So I see that I would define the event $b$ and $c$ happening as $(b,c$), and this would be it's own element, so a set containing this outcome would be like $C = \{(b,c), ...\}$? I feel like I'm close to it clicking, I just need some other nudge!

Comment: There is no outcome $(b, c)$. Again, imagine a dice. We will never get both 3 and 4 at the same time. Note that knowing that event happened when we got particular roll result doesn't completely determine the event: it's possible that we got "number greater than 1 rolled" and "even number rolled" simultaneously. So, while $B$ and $B'$ are different sets, if outcome $b$ happened, the difference is irrelevant to them happening (but if $c$ would happen, that difference would come into play).

Comment: Hi @mihalid I think the thinking has clicked now! Thanks again for the clarification. I can think about set $B = \{a,b\}$ NOT as being defined by both outcomes occurring $\{b,c\} = \{b\} \cap \{c\}$, but as a collection of possible outcomes, of which only one has to occur to make set B (our Event) Occur. Hence I assume the notation $\{b,c\} = \{b\} \cup \{c\}$ makes sense?

Comment: Yes, that's correct ($\{b, c\} = \{b\} \cup \{c\}$ is always true, it's just set-theoretical definitions).

Comment: Perfect, thanks for clarifying!